# Wallpaper setbitmap displays black screen android

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-bitmap, android-wallpaper

When using serBitmap through WallpaperManager ie.,  wallpaperManager.setBitmap(wallpaperBitmap); I am getting black screen when new wallpaper been set. How to remove the black screen when transition from old wallpaper to new wallpaper?

From where this black screen been displayed in [aosp 10](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject)?

Below is the code snippet:

```
setUserWallpaper(this,"test");

private void setUserWallPaper(final Context context, final String userName) {
        setUserWallpaperRunnable =
            new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Log.i(TAG, "setUserWallPaper() run");
                    InputStream in = null;
                    OutputStream out = null;
                    try {
                        in = new BufferedInputStream(
                            context.getContentResolver()
                            .openInputStream(
                                Uri.parse(
                                    "content://test.app.personalization.provider/" +
                                    "wall_paper" +
                                    "?user=" +
                                    userName +
                                    "&encryption=false"))
                            );
                        Bitmap wallpaperBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
                        if(wallpaperBitmap != null){
                            WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(context);
                            wallpaperManager.setBitmap(wallpaperBitmap);
                        } else {
                            Log.i(TAG, "user wallpaper is null.");
                        }
                        Log.i(TAG, "setUserWallPaper() end");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        try {
                            if (in != null) {
                                in.close();
                            }
                            if(out != null) {
                                out.close();
                            }
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
        sUserCustomizeWorker.post(setUserWallpaperRunnable);
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that the bitmap created via the stream is valid?

Comment: Yes @DarShan. I am able to get new wallpaper but black screen is displaying in between old and new wallpaper transition.

Answer (score 0):

I know this bug.
Problem: `Bitmap` is too big for wallpaper so you have to rescale the bitmap.

Rule: `bitmap width < device width * 2 and bitmap height < device height * 2`.